# Limitar quantidade de itens em um Input por valor total predefinido

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma variável com esse valor:

```
var total = 10;
```

E dois input:

```
<input type="text" name="foto-1">
<input type="text" name="foto-2">
```

> Preciso que o cliente seja impedido de por um valor no qual a soma de cada input seja superior ao **total de 10**, *DINAMICAMENTE*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão:

```
var total = 10;
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', checkInputs);
}

function checkInputs(e) {
    var sum = [].map.call(inputs, function (i) { // mapear cada input ao seu valor com Type: number
        return parseFloat(i.value) || 0;
    }).reduce(function (a, b) { // somar todos os inputs
        return a + b;
    });
    console.log(sum);
    if (sum > total ) { // verificar
        alert('valor grande demais!');
        this.value = 0;
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6to9Ltr5/

Comment: Sergio, é isso mesmo! Estava esperando por você. Agora, preciso só mais de uma coisa: Você fez com que o segundo input zerasse quando um total fosse superado, ok, você poderia fazer com que, ao invés de zerar, o input consequente obtenha o que restou da subtração entre ambos? EXEMPLO COLOQUEI : 5 e 6 Então devo colocar 5 e 5 para o usuário.

Comment: @Lollipop Sim, isso é simples, é só usar `this.value = this.value - (sum - total);`. Assim: http://jsfiddle.net/6to9Ltr5/1/